# Why Rashid Nezhmetdinov didn't achieve a grandmaster title?

Tags: history, grandmaster, famous-players, titles, tal

Rashid Nezhmetdinov is one of the greatest chess player of all time. He destroyed Mikhail Tal many times. I know he was a great attacker but Tal also a great attacker. But why Rashid did not succeed as Tal did?